# Correct implementation of toggle()?

Tags: jquery

Please could someone advise why the toggle() function is not working? Im hoping theres more to this than a simple syntax issue, rather there is a more technical reason this isnt working.

http://jsfiddle.net/LEusd/

**JS**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    console.log('Clicked...');
    $('#login-form').toggle(function(){
        console.log('Show...');
        $(this).show();
    }, function(){
        console.log('Hide...');
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" title="">Link</a>
<div id="login-form"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#login-form {
    border:1px dashed red;
    display: none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The "click" version of .toggle was removed in 1.9, it no longer can be used to bind click events. In most cases it's usage can be replaced with a single click event and a toggle method such as toggle, toggleClass, etc

Comment: Thanks Kev, I was using 1.7.2 in jsfiddle. Using toggle() with no params does the trick!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply

```
$('a').click(function(){
    console.log('Clicked...');
    $('#login-form').toggle();
});
```

**EDIT:**(*Kevin's awsome comment*)

> The "click" version of .toggle was removed in 1.9, it no longer can be used to bind click events. In most cases it's usage can be replaced with a single click event and a toggle method such as toggle, toggleClass, etc

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LEusd/1/)

Comment: Thanks Baadash, would you care to explain how this works without the need for show() and hide()?

Comment: Ahh dont worry, docs say "With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements".

Comment: @glad to help jason.Forgot to put the link to docs,Even kevin'n comment is more explanatory :).